# The code is working fine with Arduino Uno but not with NodeMCU

Tags: nodemcu

I uploaded program MPU6050_DMP6_Multiple.ino (https://github.com/eadf/MPU6050_DMP6_Multiple/blob/master/MPU6050_DMP6_Multiple.ino) to Arduino Uno and it works fine.
When I upload the very same code to NodeMCU 1.0 board in Arduino IDE I have this message from the compiler :

Errors :

```
Arduino: 1.8.5 (Windows 7), Board: "NodeMCU 1.0 (ESP-12E Module), 80 MHz, 4M (3M SPIFFS), v2 Prebuilt (MSS=536), Disabled, None, 115200"

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\arduino-builder -dump-prefs -logger=machine -hardware C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware -hardware C:\Users\Pera\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages -tools C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\tools-builder -tools C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr -tools C:\Users\Pera\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages -built-in-libraries C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries -libraries C:\Users\Pera\Documents\Arduinogttp\libraries -fqbn=esp8266:esp8266:nodemcuv2:CpuFrequency=80,FlashSize=4M3M,LwIPVariant=v2mss536,Debug=Disabled,DebugLevel=None____,UploadSpeed=115200 -ide-version=10805 -build-path C:\Users\Pera\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_960938 -warnings=none -build-cache C:\Users\Pera\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_cache_811066 -prefs=build.warn_data_percentage=75 -prefs=runtime.tools.xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc.path=C:\Users\Pera\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\tools\xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc\1.20.0-26-gb404fb9-2 -prefs=runtime.tools.mkspiffs.path=C:\Users\Pera\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\tools\mkspiffs\0.2.0 -prefs=runtime.tools.esptool.path=C:\Users\Pera\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\tools\esptool\0.4.12 -verbose C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\examples\14.Experiment\OrigMPU6050\OrigMPU6050.ino
C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\arduino-builder -compile -logger=machine -hardware C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware -hardware C:\Users\Pera\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages -tools C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\tools-builder -tools C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr -tools C:\Users\Pera\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages -built-in-libraries C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries -libraries C:\Users\Pera\Documents\Arduinogttp\libraries -fqbn=esp8266:esp8266:nodemcuv2:CpuFrequency=80,FlashSize=4M3M,LwIPVariant=v2mss536,Debug=Disabled,DebugLevel=None____,UploadSpeed=115200 -ide-version=10805 -build-path C:\Users\Pera\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_960938 -warnings=none -build-cache C:\Users\Pera\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_cache_811066 -prefs=build.warn_data_percentage=75 -prefs=runtime.tools.xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc.path=C:\Users\Pera\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\tools\xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc\1.20.0-26-gb404fb9-2 -prefs=runtime.tools.mkspiffs.path=C:\Users\Pera\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\tools\mkspiffs\0.2.0 -prefs=runtime.tools.esptool.path=C:\Users\Pera\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\tools\esptool\0.4.12 -verbose C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\examples\14.Experiment\OrigMPU6050\OrigMPU6050.ino
Using board 'nodemcuv2' from platform in folder: C:\Users\Pera\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.0
Using core 'esp8266' from platform in folder: C:\Users\Pera\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.0
Detecting libraries used...
"C:\Users\Pera\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\tools\xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc\1.20.0-26-gb404fb9-2/bin/xtensa-lx106-elf-g++" -D__ets__ -DICACHE_FLASH -U__STRICT_ANSI__ "-IC:\Users\Pera\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.0/tools/sdk/include" "-IC:\Users\Pera\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.0/tools/sdk/lwip2/include" "-IC:\Users\Pera\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.0/tools/sdk/libc/xtensa-lx106-elf/include" "-IC:\Users\Pera\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_960938/core" -c -w -Os -g -mlongcalls -mtext-section-literals -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -falign-functions=4 -std=c++11 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -w -x c++ -E -CC -DF_CPU=80000000L -DLWIP_OPEN_SRC -DTCP_MSS=536 -DARDUINO=10805 -DARDUINO_ESP8266_NODEMCU -DARDUINO_ARCH_ESP8266 -DARDUINO_BOARD="ESP8266_NODEMCU" -DESP8266 "-IC:\Users\Pera\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.0\cores\esp8266" "-IC:\Users\Pera\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.0\variants\nodemcu" "C:\Users\Pera\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_960938\sketch\OrigMPU6050.ino.cpp" -o "nul"
"C:\Users\Pera\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\tools\xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc\1.20.0-26-gb404fb9-2/bin/xtensa-lx106-elf-g++" -D__ets__ -DICACHE_FLASH -U__STRICT_ANSI__ "-IC:\Users\Pera\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.0/tools/sdk/include" "-IC:\Users\Pera\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.0/tools/sdk/lwip2/include" "-IC:\Users\Pera\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.0/tools/sdk/libc/xtensa-lx106-elf/include" "-IC:\Users\Pera\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_960938/core" -c -w -Os -g -mlongcalls -mtext-section-literals -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -falign-functions=4 -std=c++11 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -w -x c++ -E -CC -DF_CPU=80000000L -DLWIP_OPEN_SRC -DTCP_MSS=536 -DARDUINO=10805 -DARDUINO_ESP8266_NODEMCU -DARDUINO_ARCH_ESP8266 -DARDUINO_BOARD="ESP8266_NODEMCU" -DESP8266 "-IC:\Users\Pera\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.0\cores\esp8266" "-IC:\Users\Pera\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.0\variants\nodemcu" "-IC:\Users\Pera\Documents\Arduinogttp\libraries\I2Cdev" "C:\Users\Pera\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_960938\sketch\OrigMPU6050.ino.cpp" -o "nul"
"C:\Users\Pera\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\tools\xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc\1.20.0-26-gb404fb9-2/bin/xtensa-lx106-elf-g++" -D__ets__ -DICACHE_FLASH -U__STRICT_ANSI__ "-IC:\Users\Pera\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.0/tools/sdk/include" "-IC:\Users\Pera\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.0/tools/sdk/lwip2/include" "-IC:\Users\Pera\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.0/tools/sdk/libc/xtensa-lx106-elf/include" "-IC:\Users\Pera\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_960938/core" -c -w -Os -g -mlongcalls -mtext-section-literals -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -falign-functions=4 -std=c++11 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -w -x c++ -E -CC -DF_CPU=80000000L -DLWIP_OPEN_SRC -DTCP_MSS=536 -DARDUINO=10805 -DARDUINO_ESP8266_NODEMCU -DARDUINO_ARCH_ESP8266 -DARDUINO_BOARD="ESP8266_NODEMCU" -DESP8266 "-IC:\Users\Pera\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.0\cores\esp8266" "-IC:\Users\Pera\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.0\variants\nodemcu" "-IC:\Users\Pera\Documents\Arduinogttp\libraries\I2Cdev" "-IC:\Users\Pera\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.0\libraries\Wire" "C:\Users\Pera\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_960938\sketch\OrigMPU6050.ino.cpp" -o "nul"
"C:\Users\Pera\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\tools\xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc\1.20.0-26-gb404fb9-2/bin/xtensa-lx106-elf-g++" -D__ets__ -DICACHE_FLASH -U__STRICT_ANSI__ "-IC:\Users\Pera\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.0/tools/sdk/include" "-IC:\Users\Pera\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.0/tools/sdk/lwip2/include" "-IC:\Users\Pera\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.0/tools/sdk/libc/xtensa-lx106-elf/include" "-IC:\Users\Pera\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_960938/core" -c -w -Os -g -mlongcalls -mtext-section-literals -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -falign-functions=4 -std=c++11 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -w -x c++ -E -CC -DF_CPU=80000000L -DLWIP_OPEN_SRC -DTCP_MSS=536 -DARDUINO=10805 -DARDUINO_ESP8266_NODEMCU -DARDUINO_ARCH_ESP8266 -DARDUINO_BOARD="ESP8266_NODEMCU" -DESP8266 "-IC:\Users\Pera\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.0\cores\esp8266" "-IC:\Users\Pera\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.0\variants\nodemcu" "-IC:\Users\Pera\Documents\Arduinogttp\libraries\I2Cdev" "-IC:\Users\Pera\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.0\libraries\Wire" "-IC:\Users\Pera\Documents\Arduinogttp\libraries\MPU6050_DMP6_Multiple-master" "C:\Users\Pera\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_960938\sketch\OrigMPU6050.ino.cpp" -o "nul"
"C:\Users\Pera\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\tools\xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc\1.20.0-26-gb404fb9-2/bin/xtensa-lx106-elf-g++" -D__ets__ -DICACHE_FLASH -U__STRICT_ANSI__ "-IC:\Users\Pera\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.0/tools/sdk/include" "-IC:\Users\Pera\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.0/tools/sdk/lwip2/include" "-IC:\Users\Pera\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.0/tools/sdk/libc/xtensa-lx106-elf/include" "-IC:\Users\Pera\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_960938/core" -c -w -Os -g -mlongcalls -mtext-section-literals -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -falign-functions=4 -std=c++11 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -w -x c++ -E -CC -DF_CPU=80000000L -DLWIP_OPEN_SRC -DTCP_MSS=536 -DARDUINO=10805 -DARDUINO_ESP8266_NODEMCU -DARDUINO_ARCH_ESP8266 -DARDUINO_BOARD="ESP8266_NODEMCU" -DESP8266 "-IC:\Users\Pera\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.0\cores\esp8266" "-IC:\Users\Pera\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.0\variants\nodemcu" "-IC:\Users\Pera\Documents\Arduinogttp\libraries\I2Cdev" "-IC:\Users\Pera\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.0\libraries\Wire" "-IC:\Users\Pera\Documents\Arduinogttp\libraries\MPU6050_DMP6_Multiple-master" "C:\Users\Pera\Documents\Arduinogttp\libraries\I2Cdev\I2Cdev.cpp" -o "nul"
"C:\Users\Pera\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\tools\xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc\1.20.0-26-gb404fb9-2/bin/xtensa-lx106-elf-g++" -D__ets__ -DICACHE_FLASH -U__STRICT_ANSI__ "-IC:\Users\Pera\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.0/tools/sdk/include" "-IC:\Users\Pera\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.0/tools/sdk/lwip2/include" "-IC:\Users\Pera\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.0/tools/sdk/libc/xtensa-lx106-elf/include" "-IC:\Users\Pera\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_960938/core" -c -w -Os -g -mlongcalls -mtext-section-literals -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -falign-functions=4 -std=c++11 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -w -x c++ -E -CC -DF_CPU=80000000L -DLWIP_OPEN_SRC -DTCP_MSS=536 -DARDUINO=10805 -DARDUINO_ESP8266_NODEMCU -DARDUINO_ARCH_ESP8266 -DARDUINO_BOARD="ESP8266_NODEMCU" -DESP8266 "-IC:\Users\Pera\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.0\cores\esp8266" "-IC:\Users\Pera\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.0\variants\nodemcu" "-IC:\Users\Pera\Documents\Arduinogttp\libraries\I2Cdev" "-IC:\Users\Pera\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.0\libraries\Wire" "-IC:\Users\Pera\Documents\Arduinogttp\libraries\MPU6050_DMP6_Multiple-master" "C:\Users\Pera\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.0\libraries\Wire\Wire.cpp" -o "nul"
"C:\Users\Pera\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\tools\xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc\1.20.0-26-gb404fb9-2/bin/xtensa-lx106-elf-g++" -D__ets__ -DICACHE_FLASH -U__STRICT_ANSI__ "-IC:\Users\Pera\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.0/tools/sdk/include" "-IC:\Users\Pera\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.0/tools/sdk/lwip2/include" "-IC:\Users\Pera\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.0/tools/sdk/libc/xtensa-lx106-elf/include" "-IC:\Users\Pera\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_960938/core" -c -w -Os -g -mlongcalls -mtext-section-literals -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -falign-functions=4 -std=c++11 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -w -x c++ -E -CC -DF_CPU=80000000L -DLWIP_OPEN_SRC -DTCP_MSS=536 -DARDUINO=10805 -DARDUINO_ESP8266_NODEMCU -DARDUINO_ARCH_ESP8266 -DARDUINO_BOARD="ESP8266_NODEMCU" -DESP8266 "-IC:\Users\Pera\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.0\cores\esp8266" "-IC:\Users\Pera\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.0\variants\nodemcu" "-IC:\Users\Pera\Documents\Arduinogttp\libraries\I2Cdev" "-IC:\Users\Pera\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.0\libraries\Wire" "-IC:\Users\Pera\Documents\Arduinogttp\libraries\MPU6050_DMP6_Multiple-master" "C:\Users\Pera\Documents\Arduinogttp\libraries\MPU6050_DMP6_Multiple-master\MPU6050.cpp" -o "nul"
Generating function prototypes...
"C:\Users\Pera\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\tools\xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc\1.20.0-26-gb404fb9-2/bin/xtensa-lx106-elf-g++" -D__ets__ -DICACHE_FLASH -U__STRICT_ANSI__ "-IC:\Users\Pera\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.0/tools/sdk/include" "-IC:\Users\Pera\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.0/tools/sdk/lwip2/include" "-IC:\Users\Pera\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.0/tools/sdk/libc/xtensa-lx106-elf/include" "-IC:\Users\Pera\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_960938/core" -c -w -Os -g -mlongcalls -mtext-section-literals -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -falign-functions=4 -std=c++11 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -w -x c++ -E -CC -DF_CPU=80000000L -DLWIP_OPEN_SRC -DTCP_MSS=536 -DARDUINO=10805 -DARDUINO_ESP8266_NODEMCU -DARDUINO_ARCH_ESP8266 -DARDUINO_BOARD="ESP8266_NODEMCU" -DESP8266 "-IC:\Users\Pera\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.0\cores\esp8266" "-IC:\Users\Pera\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.0\variants\nodemcu" "-IC:\Users\Pera\Documents\Arduinogttp\libraries\I2Cdev" "-IC:\Users\Pera\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.0\libraries\Wire" "-IC:\Users\Pera\Documents\Arduinogttp\libraries\MPU6050_DMP6_Multiple-master" "C:\Users\Pera\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_960938\sketch\OrigMPU6050.ino.cpp" -o "C:\Users\Pera\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_960938\preproc\ctags_target_for_gcc_minus_e.cpp"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\tools-builder\ctags\5.8-arduino11/ctags" -u --language-force=c++ -f - --c++-kinds=svpf --fields=KSTtzns --line-directives "C:\Users\Pera\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_960938\preproc\ctags_target_for_gcc_minus_e.cpp"
Compiling sketch...
"C:\Users\Pera\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\tools\xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc\1.20.0-26-gb404fb9-2/bin/xtensa-lx106-elf-g++" -D__ets__ -DICACHE_FLASH -U__STRICT_ANSI__ "-IC:\Users\Pera\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.0/tools/sdk/include" "-IC:\Users\Pera\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.0/tools/sdk/lwip2/include" "-IC:\Users\Pera\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.0/tools/sdk/libc/xtensa-lx106-elf/include" "-IC:\Users\Pera\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_960938/core" -c -w -Os -g -mlongcalls -mtext-section-literals -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -falign-functions=4 -std=c++11 -MMD -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -DF_CPU=80000000L -DLWIP_OPEN_SRC -DTCP_MSS=536 -DARDUINO=10805 -DARDUINO_ESP8266_NODEMCU -DARDUINO_ARCH_ESP8266 -DARDUINO_BOARD="ESP8266_NODEMCU" -DESP8266 "-IC:\Users\Pera\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.0\cores\esp8266" "-IC:\Users\Pera\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.0\variants\nodemcu" "-IC:\Users\Pera\Documents\Arduinogttp\libraries\I2Cdev" "-IC:\Users\Pera\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.0\libraries\Wire" "-IC:\Users\Pera\Documents\Arduinogttp\libraries\MPU6050_DMP6_Multiple-master" "C:\Users\Pera\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_960938\sketch\OrigMPU6050.ino.cpp" -o "C:\Users\Pera\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_960938\sketch\OrigMPU6050.ino.cpp.o"
In file included from C:\Users\Pera\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.0\cores\esp8266/Arduino.h:244:0,

             from C:\Users\Pera\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_960938\sketch\OrigMPU6050.ino.cpp:1:

C:\Users\Pera\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.0\cores\esp8266/pgmspace.h:16:51: error: __c causes a section type conflict with __c

#define PSTR(s) (extension({static const char __c[] PROGMEM = (s); &__c[0];}))

                                               ^

C:\Users\Pera\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.0\cores\esp8266/WString.h:38:76: note: in definition of macro 'FPSTR'

#define FPSTR(pstr_pointer) (reinterpret_cast<const __FlashStringHelper *>(pstr_pointer))

                                                                        ^

C:\Users\Pera\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.0\cores\esp8266/WString.h:39:34: note: in expansion of macro 'PSTR'

#define F(string_literal) (FPSTR(PSTR(string_literal)))

                              ^

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\examples\14.Experiment\OrigMPU6050\OrigMPU6050.ino:225:20: note: in expansion of macro 'F'

 Serial.println(F("FIFO overflow!"));

                ^

C:\Users\Pera\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.0\cores\esp8266/pgmspace.h:16:51: note: '__c' was declared here

#define PSTR(s) (extension({static const char __c[] PROGMEM = (s); &__c[0];}))

                                               ^

C:\Users\Pera\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.0\cores\esp8266/WString.h:38:76: note: in definition of macro 'FPSTR'

#define FPSTR(pstr_pointer) (reinterpret_cast<const __FlashStringHelper *>(pstr_pointer))

                                                                        ^

C:\Users\Pera\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.0\cores\esp8266/WString.h:39:34: note: in expansion of macro 'PSTR'

#define F(string_literal) (FPSTR(PSTR(string_literal)))

                              ^

C:\Users\Pera\Documents\Arduinogttp\libraries\MPU6050_DMP6_Multiple-master/DeathTimer.h:45:22: note: in expansion of macro 'F'

     Serial.print(F("S:")); Serial.println(time % 60);

                  ^

Using library I2Cdev in folder: C:\Users\Pera\Documents\Arduinogttp\libraries\I2Cdev (legacy)
Using library Wire at version 1.0 in folder: C:\Users\Pera\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.0\libraries\Wire
Using library MPU6050_DMP6_Multiple-master in folder: C:\Users\Pera\Documents\Arduinogttp\libraries\MPU6050_DMP6_Multiple-master (legacy)
exit status 1
Error compiling for board NodeMCU 1.0 (ESP-12E Module).
```

I am not so good in programming to understand what I can do to solve the problem !
I'd like to use NodeMCU with two MPU6050 and I need help !

Comment: you have not asked a question. ...... what research have you done?

Comment: While we wait for a 2nd approval on the edit a kind person did for you on your question, may I ask if you have successfully compiled a simple program for the NodeMCU.  As the Arduino Uno and the NodeMCU used completely different processors, you need to take care that both are setup correctly in your IDE.

Comment: jsotola , the question is: can You help me understanding this compiler message : :   "Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.0\cores\esp8266/pgmspace.h:16:51: error: __c causes a section type conflict with __c " ?

Comment: st2000, about NodeMCU  setup You can see from the first line of compiler message "Arduino: 1.8.5 (Windows 7), Board: "NodeMCU 1.0 (ESP-12E Module), 80 MHz, 4M (3M SPIFFS), v2 Prebuilt (MSS=536)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is [an issue](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/issues/2078) in esp8266 Arduino core. It is hard to explain, but here is a workaround for you:

In MPU6050_Wrapper.h change word `__FlashStringHelper` to `char` for function `halt` to be `void halt(const char* errMessage = NULL)`.

In DeathTimer.h remove `#include <Arduino.h>`.

In sketch add before includes `#define F(s) s` to hide the F macro.

Comment: Juraj, MY HAT OFF !!! Thanks for your guidance.It works now like a charm ! I think there is no many people with knowledge like yours !